# Bootstrap 4 beta using rubygem doesn't work with Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bootstrap-4

I just start using Jekyll recently for my personal project.

I'm using `Jekyll-assets` together with `gem 'bootstrap-sass';` and everything works with charm.

This is what my main.css.scss look like:

```
@import '_sass/variables';
@import '_sass/scaffolding';
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
@import 'font-awesome';
```

Everything works when I run jekyll serve.
However, when I try to use the latest beta version,
I got this error when I try to run `Jekyll Serve`

```
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating...
Error in _assets/css/main.scss:7 File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
/Users/MacBookPro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.7.0/assets/stylesheets
/Users/MacBookPro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.7.0/assets/fonts
```

I commented out the `@import 'bootstrap-sprockets.`
It seems that `Jekyll-assets` does not found the bootstrap path.
I've already follow the step-by-step guide as stated in the documentation at [https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem][1]

Currently I'm not using any package manager such as npm,yarn etc. Any help?